# Laravel query how to join data from multimple tables

Tags: database, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-query-builder, laravel-controller

need help to join more than one table in laravel query

```
Matches table   

id
round
league_id
home_team_id
away_team_id
match_date


Match facts table   
id
match_id
player_id
minutes
goals
```

this query gets home and away team players together:

```
$MatchFacts = Match_fact::where('match_id', $match->id)
    ->get();
```

the goal is to get all match facts by team players.

Comment: So, you can use `join` for it. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with this query:

```
$away_team_facts = DB::table('match_facts')
            ->where('match_id', $match->id)
            ->join('players', 'match_facts.player_id', '=', 'players.id')
            ->where('players.team_id', '=', $awayTeamId)
            ->get();
```